# Flipper: Hermes debugger cannot connect error: "Debugging connection was closed"

Tags: react-native, fbflipper

I have downloaded and setup flipper desktop on my windows machine and I am able to run all its features properly including react devtools but somehow hermes debugger doesn't work and shows error message "Debugging connection was closed".
I am using react 16.13.1 and react-native 0.63.2 and I am running app on Samasung Galaxy Note 10 device. Tried multiple thigs suggested by people on internet but nothing seems to work.
Please refer below image[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Start your project with this command:

```
react-native start --host localhost
```